# Animation not working on matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to make an animation of the shape an exponential distribution as the sample size increases (from 100 to 1000). There is also a slider to configure the lambda parameter of the distribution and a button to start the animation.

My problem is that even though the layout gets rendered, when I press the start button no animation occurs. Here's my attempt so far:

*Editted to simplify things, I am running it in the Python notebook:*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

n0 = 100
n1 = 1000

#Create figure object
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)

#Create Sliders for parameters
axlam = plt.axes([0.20, 0.05, 0.20, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

slam = Slider(axlam, 'Exp lambda', 0, 5, valinit=1)

#Default distributions
dexp = np.random.exponential(1, n1)

#Updates distributions when sliders are changed
def updateDist(val):
    lam = slam.val
    dexp = np.random.exponential(lam, n1)

slam.on_changed(updateDist)

#updates plot on FuncAnimation call
def update(curr):
    if( curr == (n1-n0) ):
        a.event.source.stop()
    plt.cla()
    bins_exp = np.arange(0,4/slam.val,0.25)
    ax.hist(dexp[:(n0+curr)],bins=bins_exp)
    ax.set_title('Exp n={}'.format(n0+curr))

#Define Start button and function to start animation
goax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(goax, 'Start', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')    

a = None
def start(event):
    a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update,interval=100)
button.on_clicked(start)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mind the namespaces of functions.

Consider

```
a = 0
def f():
    a = 1
f()
print(a) # will print 0
```

So you need to work on the actual objects and not some local copy of them.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button

n0 = 100
n1 = 1000

#Create figure object
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)

#Create Sliders for parameters
axcolor = "skyblue"
axlam = plt.axes([0.20, 0.05, 0.20, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

slam = Slider(axlam, 'Exp lambda', 0, 5, valinit=1)

#Default distributions
dexp = [np.random.exponential(1, n1)]

##Updates distributions when sliders are changed
def updateDist(val):
    lam = slam.val
    dexp[0] = np.random.exponential(lam, n1)

slam.on_changed(updateDist)

#updates plot on FuncAnimation call
def update(curr):
    if( curr == (n1-n0) ):
        a.event.source.stop()
    ax.clear()
    bins_exp = np.arange(0,4/slam.val,0.25)
    ax.hist(dexp[0][:(n0+curr)],bins=bins_exp)
    ax.set_title('Exp n={}'.format(n0+curr))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

#Define Start button and function to start animation
goax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(goax, 'Start', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')    

a = [0]
def start(event):
    a[0] = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update,interval=100)
button.on_clicked(start)

plt.show()
```