# Changing animation parameters interactively in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, python-interactive

I need to animate something rather simple but I do need as well a slider to let the user interactively changes the parameters of the animation. I'd like it to happen online; i.e. if the user changes a parameter while the animation is playing, the animation should transit smoothly from its old dynamics to its new one.

So far I've written a function that takes arguments and makes an animation. But it's not interactive in the sense I mentioned before. There are no sliders or anything really interactive in my code. Nevertheless, the animation part is running smoothly at least.

Here is a simplified version of my code: A point revolves around the center with a specified distance `r` from the center and an angular velocity `w`. User can give them as arguments to see the animation. (If you saw something in the code that is never used don't bother yourself with it, it is probably because I forgot to trim it from the original code with is much longer.)

```py
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def simplified_code(w,r):

    fps = 36
    M = int(.75*fps*2*np.pi/w) 
    T_final = 2*np.pi/w*16

    def positions(t):
        x = r*np.cos(w*t) 
        y = r*np.sin(w*t) 
        return x,y

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal', autoscale_on=False, )
    ax.grid()

    # position
    x_e, y_e = [], []  

    # trajectory and center 
    traj_e, = plt.plot([],[],'-g',lw=1)
    e, = plt.plot([], [], 'ok')

    # time
    time_text = ax.text(0.02, 0.95, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

    def init():
        ax.set_xlim(-(r+0.5), (r+0.5))
        ax.set_ylim(-(r+0.5), (r+0.5))    
        ax.plot([0], ms=7, c='k',marker='o')
        return d,e,traj_e


    def update(frame):

        x,y = positions(frame)

        x_e.append(x)
        y_e.append(y)

        traj_e.set_data(x_e[-M:], y_e[-M:])
        e.set_data(x, y)
        time_text.set_text('time = %.1f' % frame)

        return traj_d,traj_e,d,e, orb


    return FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, T_final, T_final*fps),
                        init_func=init, blit=True, interval=1./36*1000)
```

Note that it's possible to stop the animation, change the parameters via a slider and rerun it. I want to avoid this *pause* in the animation. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't see any slider in the code. What happens if you use one?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest As I mentioned, my code is not interactive and it just takes arguments as regular functions and my goal is to make it interactive. I wanted to try [jupyter interactive widget](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Flickering-and-jumping-output) but I realized it's too slow for what I intend to do. I'm not sure how to it with matplotlib's slider without interupting the animation.

Comment: Ok, so your first problem is to create sliders at all. Check existing questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227474/animation-not-working-on-matplotlib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I managed to combine `update` function of the animation and the one with the sliders:

```py
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation 
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal', autoscale_on=False, position=[.15,.15,.75,.75] )
ax.grid()

w = 2
r = 1
fps = 36
M= 1024#
T_final = 256

x_e, y_e = [], []  
orb_x, orb_y = [], [] 

# trajectories
traj_e, = ax.plot(x_e,y_e,'-g',lw=1)

# center 
e, = ax.plot([], [], 'ok')

# orbit
orb, = ax.plot([], [], '.r',ms=1)

# time
time_text = ax.text(0.02, 0.95, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

def positions(t):
    x = r*np.cos(w*t) # epicycle
    y = r*np.sin(w*t) # epicycle
    return x,y

def orbit(r):
    phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 360)
    orb_x =  r*np.cos(phi)
    orb_y =  r*np.sin(phi)
    return orb_x,orb_y

def init():
    ax.plot([0], ms=7, c='k',marker='o')
    return e,traj_e

def update(t):
    global r, w
    w = s_w.val
    r = s_r.val
    ax.set_xlim(-(r)*1.1, (r)*1.1)
    ax.set_ylim(-(r)*1.1, (r)*1.1)  

    x,y = positions(t)

    x_e.append(x)
    y_e.append(y)
    traj_e.set_data(x_e[-M:-1], y_e[-M:-1])
    orb.set_data(orbit(r))
    e.set_data(x, y)

    time_text.set_text('time = %.1f' % t)
    return traj_e,e, orb

ax_w = plt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.35, 0.03])#, facecolor=axcolor)
ax_r = plt.axes([0.55, 0.05, 0.35, 0.03])#, facecolor=axcolor)

s_w = Slider(ax_w, r'$\omega$', -20, 20, valinit=w, valstep=0.2)
s_r = Slider(ax_r, r'r', 0, 5, valinit=r, valstep=0.2)
s_w.on_changed(update)
s_r.on_changed(update)

def anim():
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    return FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, T_final, T_final*fps),
                        init_func=init, blit=True, interval=30)

anim()
```

Using this piece of code I can change the values of `r` and `w` without pausing or restarting the animation from scratch. Another problem appears with this code though which is that the point *jumps* to some random position on the circle and then jumps back the expected trajectory. I'd address it in another question.